# Awk to compare All the files in a directory & display the frequency of occurrence

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

Suppose in  a directory I have 3  files, File 1, File 2 & File 3.  with same header name
Is it possible in awk  to compare & write the frequency of occurrence

```
File 1

C1  C2  C3  C4
a   d   a   d
a   d   a   d
a   d   a   d



File 2

C1  C2  C3  C4
a   d   a   d
a   v   a   d
a   d   a   d

File 3 

C1  C2  C3  C4
a   d   r   d
a   f   a   d
a   d   a   d
```

Step 1 compare File 1 & File 2

```
Temp.output

C1  C2  C3  C4
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0
```

Then the compare File 2 & File 3 & overwrite Temp.output with the frequency

```
Final.Output
C1  C2  C3  C4
0   0   1   0
0   2   0   0
0   0   0   0
```

the original directory may contain multiple files, and i want each of them process in orderly manner, ie. File1.txt with file2.txt then file2.txt with file3.txt

Comment: Could it be composing a 4x4 matrix and whenever the cell at (x, y) is different from file n to n+1, then increment result cell at (x, y)?

Comment: no that's only for the visual representation.... to let you understand where the change is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest you to convert your input files into lines. With this, you can apply `awk` easily.

The `paste -s <file>` command is your ally. Below you can see how sort your files sorted and convert them to lines:

```
$ cat File1.txt 
C1  C2  C3  C4
a   d   a   d
a   d   a   d
a   d   a   d
$ ls
File1.txt  File2.txt  File3.txt
$ ls | sort
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
$ ls | sort | xargs -L 1 -I {} /bin/bash -c 'echo -n {}" "; paste -s {}'
File1.txt C1  C2  C3  C4    a   d   a   d   a   d   a   d   a   d   a   d
File2.txt C1  C2  C3  C4    a   d   a   d   a   v   a   d   a   d   a   d
File3.txt C1  C2  C3  C4    a   d   r   d   a   f   a   d   a   d   a   d
$
```

Once into lines, you can use awk to iterate the fields (`NF` will tell you how many are there). We will use several rules.

For every line, you will compare if the field at `i` is different from the previous saved value and increment the result accordingly. Skip comparing the results for the first line with the `(NR != 1)` selector.

```
(NR != 1) { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if (last[i] != $i) { result[i]++; } } }
```

In the same `awk` call, include the rule that updates the array where you keep the last values:

```
{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { last[i] = $i  }  }
```

Finally printout the file and the status of the results:

```
{ printf("%s", $1); for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf(" %d", result[i]) } print "" }
```

Here you is the whole command:

```
$ ls | sort | xargs -L 1 -I {} /bin/bash -c 'echo -n {}" "; paste -s {}' | awk '(NR != 1) { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if (last[i] != $i) { result[i]++; } } } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { last[i] = $i  }  } { printf("%s", $1); for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf(" %d", result[i]) } print "" }'
File1.txt 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
File2.txt 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
File3.txt 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
$
```

This output starts with the filename, then the accumulated differences in:

- The filename (always different)
- The columns (C1, C2, C3, C4 always the same)
- Then your 12 values. Your relevant data starts at field 7.

You can format that back again with `awk` inserting new lines when appropriate:

```
awk '{ print ""; printf("%s", $1); for (i = 7; i <= NF; i++) { if (((i - 7) % 4) == 0) print "" ; printf(" %d", $i) } print "" }'
```

Here you have a complete run:

```
$ ls | sort | xargs -L 1 -I {} /bin/bash -c 'echo -n {}" "; paste -s {}' | awk '(NR != 1) { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if (last[i] != $i) { result[i]++; } } } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { last[i] = $i  }  } { printf("%s", $1); for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf(" %d", result[i]) } print "" }' | awk '{ print ""; printf("%s", $1); for (i = 7; i <= NF; i++) { if (((i - 7) % 4) == 0) print "" ; printf(" %d", $i) } print "" }'

File1.txt
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0

File2.txt
 0 0 0 0
 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0

File3.txt
 0 0 1 0
 0 2 0 0
 0 0 0 0
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the awk script below. row = 4 includes header as well

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/awk '{print $0;}' /tmp/file* | awk -v row=4 -v col=4 '
{
    x = (NR - 1)%row;
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){
        if(a[x, i] != $i){
            a[x, i] = $i;
            count[x, i]++;
        }
    }
}END{
    for(i = 1; i <= row-1; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            printf (count[i, j]-1)" ";
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
}'
```

#

Below script is to print each iterations

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/awk '{print $0;}' /tmp/stack/file* | awk -v row=4 -v col=4 '
{
    x = (NR - 1)%row;
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){
        if(a[x, i] != $i){
            a[x, i] = $i;
            count[x, i]++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= row-1; i++){
                for(j = 1; j <= col; j++){
                        printf (count[i, j]-1)" ";
                }
                printf "\n";
        }
    print "***********";

}END{
    for(i = 1; i <= row-1; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= col; j++){
            printf (count[i, j]-1)" ";
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
}'
```